# What does ... [, param] mean in Python library documentation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameters

I saw this in the [Python standard library documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html):

```
class bytearray([source[, encoding[, errors]]])
```

I don't understand the difference between `([source[, encoding[, errors]]])` and

`(source, encoding, errors)`. Why do they put `[,  ]` around parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those args. are optional but both are need.

Answer (score 2):

It means those arguments are optional.

Comment: Then why not use `param=None` instead?

Comment: @KennyChau, (in addition to the reasons Hai adds below): `[, errors]` doesn't tell you that passing `errors=None` will have the same effect as leaving `errors` out entirely, whereas documenting `errors=None` makes such a guarantee. Consider if an implementation reads `*args`, or has a constant sigil other than `None` as default.

Comment: Using brackets you can convey more information. By nesting them you can say encoding is optional but only once you have specified source. So from above example, you can do bytearray(source, encoding) and bytearray(source) but not bytearray(encoding)

Answer (score 1):

required [optional] required [optional, but both needed].